# problem with writing to 2 databases from Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I was trying this code from github:https://github.com/kodinor/spring-data-many-dbs
It's an example of how to use multiple db's from a Spring-boot application. it worked fine but I added the Spring-boot-starter-web dependency and now I'm getting an error:

```
>Method requestMappingHandlerMapping in >org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$En>ableWebMvcConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>   - productDSEmFactory: defined by method 'productDSEmFactory' in class >path resource [com/kodinor/configuration/ProductDBConfiguration.class]
>   - userDSEmFactory: defined by method 'userDSEmFactory' in class path >resource [com/kodinor/configuration/UserDBConfiguration.class]
>
>
>Action:
>
>Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to >accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should >be consumed<br>
```

I have two config files:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement 
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class,  entityManagerFactoryRef = "userDSEmFactory", transactionManagerRef = "userDSTransactionManager")
    public class UserDBConfiguration {

        @Primary
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource1")
        public DataSourceProperties userDSProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean
        public DataSource userDS(@Qualifier("userDSProperties") DataSourceProperties userDSProperties) {
            return userDSProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean     userDSEmFactory(@Qualifier("userDS") DataSource userDS, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder.dataSource(userDS).packages(User.class).build();
    }
        @Primary
        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager userDSTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory userDSEmFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(userDSEmFactory);
        }

    }
```

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = ProductRepository.class,     entityManagerFactoryRef = "productDSEmFactory", transactionManagerRef = "productDSTransactionManager")
    public class ProductDBConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource2")
        public DataSourceProperties productDSProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource productDS(@Qualifier("productDSProperties")  DataSourceProperties productDSProperties) {
        return productDSProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean productDSEmFactory(@Qualifier("productDS") DataSource productDS, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder.dataSource(productDS).packages(Product.class).build();
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager productDSTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory productDSEmFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(productDSEmFactory);
        }

    }
```

Application.properties:

```
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

    spring.datasource1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    spring.datasource1.username=user
    spring.datasource1.password=pass

    spring.datasource2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    spring.datasource2.username=user
    spring.datasource2.password=pass
```

And a simple main app that adds some init data:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringDataManyDbsApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataManyDbsApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Autowired
        private ProductRepository productRepository;

        @PostConstruct
        void init () {

            User user = new User("john", "doe");
            userRepository.save(user);

            Product product = new Product("chair", 5);
            productRepository.save(product);
        }
}
```

I tried to add the @Primary annotation to userDSEmFactory. The error goes away but the product data isn't saved anymore. Any ideas how to save this problem? I don't have a lot of experience with Spring-boot and I've read dozens of articles but many seem to do things in a different way. Thanks so much for helping me out!

**update**

I've added the @Primary annotation like this:

```
        @Primary  
        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean     userDSEmFactory(@Qualifier("userDS") DataSource userDS, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder.dataSource(userDS).packages(User.class).build();
    }
```

No there are no more errors, but only the user is being saved in the primary db and  nothing is being saved to the product (second) database.
So if anybody has suggestions what could be the cause of that..

Comment: Can  you elaborate on what "product data isn't saved anymore" means? - Is it that your `productRepository.save(product);` call seems to have no effect?  What do you . mean by "anymore?".  Was there a time when only had code for the product repository in your database, and it was working?  Are there errors in the log output pertaining to that call?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the product isn't saved anymore. The save(product) function doesn't seem to do anything. It did work before i added the Maven Spring-boot-starter-web dependency. But I've noticed something weird: When I remove the dependency and run the main application it does save data and also the data from the attempts where it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources) example.

Comment: Have you checked the Spring Boot doc? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-two-entity-managers

Comment: @NikolayHristov Thanks for your reply. I tried your example but It gave so many errors and dependency problems. Also I'm not too fond of the Lombok notations. I'm a bit strapped for time and I didn't have the patience to try and fix all the errors. I'd rather fix my original project. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: I did, but I couldn't really find anything useful regarding my project. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@Primary` annotation on your `userDSEmFactory`

```
@Primary
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userDSEmFactory(@Qualifier("userDS") DataSource userDS, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder.dataSource(userDS).packages(User.class).build();
}
```

And also it is goot to use once `@EnableTransactionManagement` at your main class.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried the @Primary annotation like you suggested already. No errors then, but then the product data doesn't get saved. I should have witten that clearer in my original post. I will try your other suggestion this evening.

Comment: Unfortunately the @EnableTransactionManagement didn't work either